# Correct way to return stream from azure openai sdk api

Tags: c#, .net, azure, openai-api, azure-openai

I am trying to return stream result from azure openai api, could anyone tell if the last line in below method will return full content or will it miss the content not received from api. . Also, Is this the correct way to return stream from Azure OpenAI SDK streaming api?

```
public async Task<Stream> GetStreamResponse(CompletionsRequest rawAzureOpenAIRequest)
{
    rawAzureOpenAIRequest = new CompletionsRequest();
    rawAzureOpenAIRequest.ModelToUse = DefaultTextModelToUse;
    CompletionsOptions optns = new CompletionsOptions();
    optns.Prompts.Add("below is the summary of technical consultant role in software");

    var azResponse = await _openAIRepository
        .GetRawCompletionStreamingResponse(rawAzureOpenAIRequest.ModelToUse, optns,
        canToken);

    return azResponse.GetRawResponse().ContentStream;
}
```

Below is the method description from azure, but I am not clear what "returns null for responses without content" means here. Could it refer to the content not fetched yet ?

[image]

I found one more way to yield return using azure openai api but it is yielding in batches and not working as expected..

```
public async IAsyncEnumerable<string> GetStreamResponse(CompletionsRequest rawAzureOpenAIRequest)
{
    rawAzureOpenAIRequest = new CompletionsRequest();
    rawAzureOpenAIRequest.ModelToUse = DefaultTextModelToUse;
    CompletionsOptions optns = new CompletionsOptions();
    optns.Prompts.Add("below is the summary of technical consultant role in software");


    var azResponse = await _openAIRepository.GetStreamingResponse(rawAzureOpenAIRequest.ModelToUse, optns,
                canToken);

    await foreach (var choice in azResponse.Value.GetChoicesStreaming())
    {
        await foreach (var message in choice.GetTextStreaming())
        {
            yield return message;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to create a consuming api , it seems to return the result, but I think i might be missing some data using approach 1.

Answer (score -1):

- In first approach, the line return `azResponse.GetRawResponse().ContentStream;` will return the stream obtained from the Azure OpenAI API.
- The `ContentStream property` returns null for responses without content.

In the context of the Azure OpenAI SDK, if the API response does not have any content to return, then the ContentStream property will be null. It does not refer to the content not fetched yet.

- For the missing data using the first approach, you can check if the ContentStream is null before returning it.

C# code to handle the case where ContentStream is null.

```
public async Task<Stream> GetStreamResponse(CompletionsRequest rawAzureOpenAIRequest)
{
    rawAzureOpenAIRequest = new CompletionsRequest();
    rawAzureOpenAIRequest.ModelToUse = DefaultTextModelToUse;
    CompletionsOptions optns = new CompletionsOptions();
    optns.Prompts.Add("below is the summary of technical consultant role in software");

    var azResponse = await _openAIRepository.GetRawCompletionStreamingResponse(rawAzureOpenAIRequest.ModelToUse, optns, canToken);
    if (azResponse.GetRawResponse().ContentStream != null)
    {
        return azResponse.GetRawResponse().ContentStream;
    }
    throw new Exception("No content available from the API response.");
}
```

- For the second approach using `IAsyncEnumerable`, it gives the result in batches and returning each message as it becomes available.

For more information refer to the [azure-sdk-for-net/ResponseSamples.cs at main- GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/core/Azure.Core/tests/samples/ResponseSamples.cs) and [Github Issue.](https://github.com/openai/openai-node/issues/18)